# is there any solution to face the Error: Call to a member function myfunction() on array in?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am facing some errors with my code, actually I've read another same problem, but I cannot catch the point to solve this error, I'm using controller to fetch almost all table called including **ppdb**, <-- this table show errors **Fatal Error** Call to a member function getPdb() on array in line 64

this my code

```
<tbody>
    <?php 
        $no = 1;
        if(is_array($data->getPdb()) || is_object($data->getPdb())){ //This line 64
            foreach($data->getPdb() as $data){?>

            <tr>
                <td><?=$no++?></td>
                <td><?=$data['gelombang']?></td>
                <td><?=$data['tanggalbuka']?></td>
                <td><?=$data['tanggaltutup']?></td>
                <td><?=$data['tahunajaran']?></td>
                <td><?php  if($data['status']==1){echo 'Aktif';}else{echo 'Tidak Aktif';}?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="inc/editTa.php?status=<?php echo (($data['status'] ==1)?'2':'1');?>&id=<?php echo $data['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-<?php echo (($data['status']==2)?'success':'danger');?>"><i class="fa fa-<?php echo (($data['status']==2)?'check':'check');?>"></I></a>&nbsp<?php echo (($data['status'] == 2)?'AKtifkan':'Non Aktifkan');?>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <?php } } ?>
</tbody>
```

in my controller the code written like this:

```
    $getta = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ppdb");
    $getta->execute();
    $c = $getta->rowcount();
    if($c > 0){
        foreach($getta as $data){
            $hasil[] = $data;
        }
        return $hasil;
    }
}
```

And the error shown like this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPdb() on array in D:\xampp\htdocs\nh\inc\view\admin\inc\ppdb.php:64 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\nh\inc\view\admin\index.php(31): include() #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\nh\inc\view\admin\inc\ppdb.php on line 64
```

Above this table I use another function to save the form and fetch the option:

```
<form class="form animated bounceIn" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php 
                    $data->createPpdb();
                 ?>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header bg-dark">
                    Setting Gelombang PPPDB
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="gelombang" title="Nama Gelombang" class="form-control" placeholder="contoh: Gelombang I">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="tanggalbuka" title="Tanggal Buka PPDB" class="form-control" placeholder="Pilih Tanggal" id="tbuka">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="tanggaltutup" title="Tanggal Tutup PPDB" class="form-control" placeholder="Pilih Tanggal" id='ttutup'>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" name="ta">
                            <option value="" disbaled>-Pilih Tahun Ajaran-</option>
                            <?php 
                                if(is_array($data->getTa()) || is_object($data->getTa())){
                                    foreach($data->getTa() as $data){?>
                                        <option value="<?=$data['tahunajaran']?>"><?=$data['tahunajaran']?></option>
                            <?php
                                    }
                                }
                             ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="simpanppdb" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="Simpan">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I'd read with similar problem from stacoverflow.com but I cannot get the point.

Thank you for someone who save my day.

Comment: The error means that `$data` is an array, not an object. What do you expect `$data->getPdb()` to do?

Comment: @Barmar [I thought you might want to see this before it gets deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59997342/1415724) or you didn't see what they wanted you to see. I doubt you got the ping they tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're reusing the variable `$data` in the line:

```
foreach($data->getPdb() as $data){
```

So `$data` starts out being an object, but after the loop it contains the last row of the results, which is an array. The next time you try to call `$data->getPdb()` you'll get an error.

Use different variables, like this:

```
foreach ($data->getPdb() as $item) {
```

Also, you shouldn't call `$data->getPdb()` repeatedly. Each time you do `is_array($data->getPdb())` and `is_object($data->getPdb())` it performs the full query and collects all the results. Do it once and save the result in a variable.

```
$pdb = $data->getPdb();
if (is_array($pdb) || is_object($pdb)) {
    foreach ($pdb as $item) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer all, I've solved this with my own way and it took from Mr. @Braham comment, I try to combine the variable and re-initiate the class.

this the solving problem

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="ppdb">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Gelombang</th>
                    <th>Tanggal Buka</th>
                    <th>Tanggal Tutup</th>
                    <th>Tahun Ajaran</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Opsi</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                    $no = 1;
                    $item = new NurulHuda(); // This re-initiate Class 
                    if(is_array($item->getPpdb()) || is_object($item->getPpdb())){
                        foreach($item->getPpdb() as $val){?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?=$no++?></td>
                            <td><?=$val['gelombang']?></td>
                            <td><?=$val['tanggalbuka']?></td>
                            <td><?=$val['tanggaltutup']?></td>
                            <td><?=$val['tahunajaran']?></td>
                            <td><?php  if($val['status']==1){echo 'Aktif';}else{echo 'Tidak Aktif';}?></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="inc/editTa.php?status=<?php echo (($val['status'] ==1)?'2':'1');?>&id=<?php echo $val['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-<?php echo (($val['status']==2)?'success':'danger');?>"><i class="fa fa-<?php echo (($val['status']==2)?'check':'check');?>"></I></a>&nbsp<?php echo (($val['status'] == 2)?'AKtifkan':'Non Aktifkan');?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                <?php } } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Thank you Mr. @Braham for lighting me...

Comment: Is @Braham supposed to be me? You misspelled it, and there's also no notifications for mentions in answers, only in comments.

Comment: What is `$item`, and how did you set it differently from `$data` in the question?